# How to keep controls' url within a module in dnn?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, module, dotnetnuke

I create a module in DNN 7, which have 10 controls. These controls call through each other with different parameters.
i need to keep the navigation URL of my controls in order to use in "Back" button in each control. 
I used this code : Response.Redirect(DotNetNuke.Common.Globals.NavigateURL());
but it returns to the very first control of my module.

How can i have a simple breadcrumb like object within my module which keeps previous control with all its parameters?

Answer (score 0):

You can store the last control and all the parameters in a Session variable:

```
Session["LastControlKey"] = "Edit";
```

...and get the values again using:

```
string lastControl = (string)Session["LastControlKey"];
```

More examples for the session variable on MSDN: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6ad7zeeb.ASPX

Edit: To get the control's URL, you can use NavigateURL with the control's key:

```
DotNetNuke.Common.Globals.NavigateURL(this.TabId, lastControl)
```

Comment: as i said my controls call through each other, and using session means that i should save urls in a list and i'm not sure if it is suitable?! Is there any alternative way?